# Add elements to existing React DropdownButton

Tags: javascript, react-bootstrap

I am using react and react-boostrap.

I have created a Dropdown Button which on render has no Dropdown.Item elements inside. When useEffect is called, I'm trying to append results from a server into the dropdown button.

My HTML is the following:

```html
<Container className="mt-3">
  <InputGroup>
    <DropdownButton as={InputGroup.Prepend} title="Existing Label" id="input-group-dropdown-1">
      <Dropdown.Item></Dropdown.Item>
    </DropdownButton>
    <FormControl id="nameForm" placeholder="Name of person" />
    <FormControl id="labelForm" placeholder="Label: Criminal or Citizen" />
  </InputGroup>
</Container>
```

My code to append the elements is the following:

```
    var dropdownItem = document.createElement("Dropdown.Item");
    dropdownItem.value = jsonArray[i];
    var splitString = jsonArray[i].split("-");
    var formNameText = splitString[0].replace(' ', '');
    var formLabelText = splitString[1].replace(' ', '');
    dropdownItem.onClick = "{changeFormText(formNameText, formLabelText)}"
    document.getElementById('input-group-dropdown-1').append(dropdownItem)
```

My issue is, that no elements end up inside the DropdownButton tag. I have tried using innerHTML, however it seems to overwrite the text field of the parent button.

I might be misunderstanding basic elements of react, but haven't been able to find a solution through google.

Comment: Can you show the response of server? I mean if it is data inside an object you can put that in an array and set that array to any state and map it out inside jsx?

Comment: The array that is returned from the server contains 4 elements, which are all strings.

Array(4) [ "Person_1", "Person_2", "Person_3", "Person_4" ]

Comment: I forgot to mention, that the above code is run inside a loop, to iterate over each string. I do not belive the handeling of strings or array is the issue at hand. Passing simple strings without touching the arrray yields the same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your comment your response is an array what you can do is to set that array to any state

If you are using functional component then do something like this

```
const [dropdown,setDropdown] = React.useState([]);

// Inside your useEffect  you can do something like this

useEffect(()=>{
// After your server response
setDropdown(response);
},[])

// Then your jsx will be like this

    <DropdownButton as={InputGroup.Prepend} title="Existing Label" id="input-group-dropdown-1">
      {dropdown.map((item,i)=><Dropdown.Item key={i}>{item}</Dropdown.Item>)}
    </DropdownButton>
```

This will only show data after your server response so i hope it helps

Comment: Thank you, this definetly put me in the right direction. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Just an addition to my comment. I had trouble adding an onClick attribute to the dropdown item. Turns out his is a bug in bootstrap since 2018.

It can be sovled by encapsulating your function call in another function call "() => functionHere()".

This resulted in a change that looks like this: {dropdown.map((item,i) => <Dropdown.Item key={i} onClick={() => addOnClickToId(item)} id={item}>{item}</Dropdown.Item>)}

Anyways, everything works now :)

Answer (score 0):

you could append elements based on a model in `jsx`.

```
const Component = ({items}) => {
   return (
   <Container className="mt-3">
    <InputGroup>
      <DropdownButton as={InputGroup.Prepend} title="Existing Label" id="input-group-dropdown-1">
        {
           items.map((name, index) => (<DropdownButton.Item key={index}>{name}</DropdownButton.Item>))
        }
      </DropdownButton>
      <FormControl id="nameForm" placeholder="Name of person" />
      <FormControl id="labelForm" placeholder="Label: Criminal or Citizen" />
    </InputGroup>
  </Container>
   )
}
```

assuming items is an array of strings you want to add to dropdown

Comment: Is this possible to do when useEffect is called after the render? I need to fetch these items from my server before i can serve them to the DropdownButton.

Comment: just provide an empty list when you have no data from the state and update it it will auto-rerender  the dropdown. just not that items has to be either provided by the `props` or by the `state` of the component to be rerendered